# Cannot assign a value of type '[CFString]' to a value of type '[String]'

Tags: xcode7, cfstring, xcode7-beta5

I just downloaded the new Xcode 7 beta 5 and I cannot find a way to resolve this error.  It keeps highlighting the line "pickker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]" and says "Cannot assign a value of type '[CFString]' to a value of type '[String]'"

```
if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage]
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        NSLog("No Camera.")
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Try casting the CFString to a String like so:

```
picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks Cloud9999Strife

Comment: @MatthewSmith your welcome. Accept the answer if you are happy with it.